# Storing Dovecot Sieve scripts with SQL database

Tags: dovecot

I'm not sure how to set up Dovecot to use SQL database for sieve storage. So far I found Pigeonhole with this tutorial - https://wiki.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Configuration/Dict

From what I understand the idea here is to use dictionary with Sieve scripts stored in SQL database. But one sentence is not clear from me

> As with the flat file, the database query will need to return the
>   Sieve script all in one line, otherwise the subsequent lines will be
>   ignored.

So in that case is it possible to retrieve only sieve scripts for given email?
I'm trying to find a way to have let say 100 different scripts for 100 different emails. So some would look like this:

```
require ["envelope", "fileinto", "mailbox"];
if envelope "To" "personal@example.com"
{
    fileinto :create "Personal";
}
```

another like that

```
 require ["envelope", "fileinto", "mailbox"]; 
 if envelope "To" "office@example.com" 
 {
     redirect :copy "office@example.net";
 }
```

But always `To` would be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your environment, so I will try to answer based on general
database knowledge. Here is how I understand the documentation in your
link.

I believe that the documentation refers to an SQL database (which product?)
connected-to with the connection string of:

```
host=localhost dbname=dovecot user=dovecot password=password
```

This means that the database server should be running on the same computer,
the database to be named `dovecot`, and have a user account named `dovecot`
with the password of `password`.
I assume that these can be changed, as the `connect` string is an updateable
parameter of the script.

The database should contain a table named `user_sieve_scripts`,
which could maybe be a parameter coming from the configuration file.

The table should have two columns (maybe also configuration parameters):

- `username` : The key to be searched, which in your case would be the `to`
  field,
- `id` : The column which contains the script to use.

The script must be entirely contained within the `id` column, because only
one database access will be done on the table, so this column must be large
enough to contain your longest script.

The `id` column presumably includes line-feeds between lines,
or none if the script language supports multi-command lines
(I don't know this product well enough).

I hope that this can point you in the right direction.